# realloc not working despite using it on a malloc'ed string

Tags: c, debugging, malloc, free, realloc

I'm not really sure why this is happening but in the code below I made a simple program to help me understand how malloc works. I was basically trying to see how resizing arrays works in term of memory addresses.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    
    char* buff;
    buff = malloc(10);
    buff = "hi";
    printf("%c\n", buff[0]);
    printf("%p\n", &buff[0]);

   if (realloc(buff, (size_t) 20) == NULL){
       printf("no\n");
       exit(1);
   }
    
    printf("%p\n", &buff[0]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, realloc returns NULL. Here it is running with valgrind.

```
valgrind ./test
==3421== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3421== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3421== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3421== Command: ./test
==3421==
h
0x400734
==3421== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3421==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3421==    by 0x400673: main (in /home/puf311/cs3733/practice/test)
==3421==  Address 0x400734 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3421==
no==3421==
==3421== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3421==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==3421==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 15 bytes allocated
==3421==
==3421== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3421==    definitely lost: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==3421==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3421==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3421==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3421==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3421== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3421==
==3421== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3421== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As far as I know, the string is malloc'ed, and I definitely didn't free it earlier. So, what's going on here?

Comment: [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) returns the *new* pointer. If you don't save it, you loose the memory. But remember, if `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`, the old pointer is still valid, so don't reassign back to the same pointer you pass as argument to `realloc`.

Comment: `buf = "hi";` throws away the pointer that was returned by `malloc` and replaces it with a pointer to a string literal. You can't pass a pointer to a string literal to `realloc`. If you want to put the string `"hi"` into the memory that `malloc` returned, then use `strcpy(buf, "hi");`.

Comment: With `buff = "hi";` you reassign the original pointer returned by `malloc`. It's like doing `int a = 10; a = 5;` and then wondering why `a` isn't equal to `10` anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
buff = malloc(10);
buff = "hi";
```

You've reassigned the address held in `buff`...

You probably meant:

```
strcpy( buff, "hi" );
```

And, you need to capture the returned pointer from `realloc()` in case that function has relocated your data to grow/shrink the buffer.

Further, ALWAYS check return codes from any system call. You probably test if `fopen()` returned NULL. Well, memory allocation can fail, too!

```
char *buff = malloc( 10 );
if( buff == NULL ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "malloc failed\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); // probably not going to get much further
}
```

EDIT: That was too easy. Here's an annotated version that (omitting typos) should show how you should/could use `realloc()`

```
int main() {
    char *buff = malloc( 10 );
    if( buff == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to launch!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    strcpy( buff, "hi" ); // should fit!
    puts( buff ); // working???

    printf( "%c\n", buff[0] ); // should be 'h'

    printf( "%p\n", &buff[0] ); // should be the same as...
    printf( "%p\n",  buff    ); // this

    { // NB: 'tmp' is only within the 'scope' of this pair of braces
        char *tmp = realloc( buff, 20 ); // delicately
        if ( tmp == NULL ) {
            // Here it is, but this need not be a "hard error"
            // Report problem, but could perhaps continue with same sized buffer, somehow...
            fprintf( stderr, "Cannot grow the buffer, but,,, ");
            printf( "still have '%s' and 'Good-bye'\n", buff );
            free( buff );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        buff = tmp; // Got it. (Don't replace if "soft error" of tmp being NULL, of course)
    }

    printf( "%p\n", buff ); // just to see if block relocated

    free( buff ); // don't forget about this

    return 0;
}
```

Caveat: It's up to you, the programmer who 'reserves' blocks of heap memory, to track how big that block is and not "scribble" outside of that playground. `free()` will do the right thing, but between `malloc()` and `free()`, and made more complex with `realloc()` there is a lot of opportunity to overrun the buffer and invoke "undefined behaviour".

Taking this one step further...

In fact, on some occasions the code is better using **only** `realloc()` that "acts like `malloc()`" when it receives a NULL as the first parameter...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char sentence[] = "The  quick brown   fox jumps   over the lazy dog";
    char **words = NULL;

    // Chop up a mutable string (sentence), isolating each word
    // accessible via its own pointer.
    // realloc() "grows" the array of pointers to words.
    int i = 0; 
    for( char *p = sentence; (p = strtok( p, " " )) != NULL; p = NULL ) {
        char **tmp = realloc( words, (i+1) * sizeof *tmp );
        if ( tmp == NULL ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "realloc failed on %d - %s\n", i, p );
            free( words );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        words = tmp;
        words[ i++ ] = p;
        printf( "cnt(%d) ", i ); // debugging
    }
    putchar( '\n' ); // debugging

    while( i-- ) // reverse order
        puts( words[i] ); 

    free( words );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
cnt(1) cnt(2) cnt(3) cnt(4) cnt(5) cnt(6) cnt(7) cnt(8) cnt(9)
dog
lazy
the
over
jumps
fox
brown
quick
The
```